# Populate values in double select box in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am populating the values in double select box dynamically from database at the time of loading.

I am successful in getting the values for the first select box but I am not getting the respective values for second select box.

Please if any body can help me to get the values in the second select I am really in need.

I am using the MAP collection.

```
<s:doubleselect label="Control" 
name="controlNameValue" list="control.keySet()" 
doubleName="controlAreaValue" doubleList="control.get(top)" />
```

Comment: We need the code of the action too.

Answer (score 0):

use `moveSelectedOptions(... ..)` on `addToLeftOnClick` and `addToRightOnClick` buttons.